# How can I do a "get" from my Visual Studio Online Account Using Powershell?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, powershell, tfs

I am setting up an automated build environment but I am having trouble connecting to my Visual Studio Online account through Powershell to fully automate the get-latest, build-project, and run-unit test process. Anyone have experience with this?

Update:

I am using TF Version Control

Comment: Are you using tfvc or git?

Comment: @mike z I am using tfvc

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use the Team Build functionality to do this. It supports what you want to do out of the box and you don't need any scripting.

If you need a script you can use the "tf.exe" commands.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(v=vs.100).aspx